# Force http to https via htaccess file, not working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate

So my issue is if I visit my website it is unsecured. However, if I put https://www.websitename.co.uk it will display the website with https and secure bar. However, when I upload my htaccess file the website just doesn't want to connect.

[image: Error message when I use the htaccess]

If I comment out the code below from the htaccess file, the website works but doesn't show secure. If I add that code it just gives me the error message as seen in the image.

```
 # Redirect http to https editor nathan 18/01/2017
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**htaccess File**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirect http to https editor nathan 18/01/2017
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect non www. to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.MYWEBSITE\.co\.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.MYWEBSITE.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1? [R=301,L]

# Remove .php ONLY if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Into this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This means if the visitor go to http (which is port 80) will get redirect to https (which is 443)

Comment: Hi there, I tried this solution and it works, however, another issue is that if I click some pages. For example, if iI visits the home page or the contact us page they show fine with working https, however, if I visit other pages such as about us or a product page it says the same message as above "This page isn't working"

Comment: It not the same message, you should read carefully.
It was "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" before, and "This page isn't working" meaning you have something not properly configured on your side.
The objective is forcing http to https and it's working, so any new problem it is up to you.